# Getting last message from each conversation sql

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table of messages in sql that's basically a column for the current user, the user he's interacting with, id and the contents of the message. I need to retrieve the last message from every distinct conversation in order to preview it.

Any idea how?

Comment: It would be nice if you provide some simple data and what you try...

Comment: And tell us which DBMS you are using.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to read all rows where there are no later message for that conversation. Something like:

```
select *
from messages m1
where not exists (select 1 from messages m2
                  where m2.messageid > m1.messageid
                    and m1.conversationid = m2.conversationid)
```

Sample output:

```
SQL>create table messages (conversationid int, messageid int);
SQL>insert into messages values (1,1);
SQL>insert into messages values (1,2);
SQL>insert into messages values (2,1);
SQL>insert into messages values (2,2);
SQL>insert into messages values (2,3);
SQL>insert into messages values (3,1);
SQL>select *
SQL&from messages m1
SQL&where not exists (select 1 from messages m2
SQL&                  where m2.messageid > m1.messageid
SQL&                    and m1.conversationid = m2.conversationid);
conversationid   messageid
============== ===========
             1           2
             2           3
             3           1

                  3 rows found
```

Comment: Yes, with your sample data it does. But I suppose the real table has a unique key (as well as additional columns.) Besides, with same messageid twice, how do you chose?

Comment: Ha ha, sorry about that. Cut and paste error. (I was working at the same time, and did the cut and paste in two parts...) Will remove the duplicate line.

Answer (score 0):

Greatest-n-per group problems are usually solved with [modern SQL](http://use-the-index-luke.com/de/blog/2015-02/modern-sql) using window functions:

```
select *
from (
  select c.*,
         row_number() over (partition by conversation_id order by message_time desc) as rn
  from conversation c
) t
where rn = 1
order by conversation_id;
```